# Execution timeout for program

Tags: executiontimeout

I have written a program, loops through 1700 rows of data and 2 columns.  It takes forever to run the program.  Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Which problem, exactly? That it takes forever to process 1700 rows?

Comment: Yes.  How can I speed up the execution of my code.

Comment: How do you think we can tell you that without seeing your code?